# Cannot mount NFS Share from Windows Server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, nfs

I am trying to mount an NFS Share from a Windows Server File-Server Cluster on a Ubuntu Host.

The connection times out when I try to mount the share like this:

```
sudo mount -t nfs fs01:/longhorn /testlonghorn
mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Using the IP of the 'active' node instead, I get a 'no such file or directory' error message:

```
sudo mount -t nfs 10.75.20.12:/longhorn /testlonghorn
mount.nfs: mounting 10.75.20.12:/longhorn failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to mount the share on a Windows host, which yields similar results:

```
C:\Users\user> mount fs01:/longhorn L:
Network Error - 53 (The network path was not found.)
```

All machines are in the same subnet. The same cluster also serves SMB shares, which works flawlessly. To rule out permissions, I have allowed Read/Write Root Access for all hosts. The properties of the share now look like this:

**General**

[image]

**Authentication**
[image]

**Permissions**
[image]

The Ubuntu host can mount NFS shares from other (Linux) hosts and the firewall rules (on the File-Server Cluster) also seem to be correct:

**Cluster Firewall Rules**
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you resolve your problem yet? I got the same issue too..

Comment: you try to access anonymously @eleasar

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem yet.
From those windows nodes, you need to allow the ports 111 and 2049 for the inbound firewall rules.
It should be worked after set.